# Protobuf oneof has_field private

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have made a simple protobuf file to reproduce my problem:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;

message Test {
    uint32 test1 = 1;
    oneof param {
        uint32 test2 = 2;
        bool test3 = 3;
    }
}
```

When I generate the c++ code the oneof's `has_param()` member function is private. Is it normal ? How do I know if the oneof is set ?

By the way I tried with protobuf 3.12.4 and 3.21.9 and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation for Protobuf C++ generated code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#oneof).

The generator creates a method `param_case()`, which returns enumeration type that identifies which field inside the `oneof` is present. If the `oneof` is empty, it returns `PARAM_NOT_SET`.

Comment: Still I find it weird that all other parameters have this field public but not the `oneof` fields.